# Checkboxes in the category list?

Tags: categories, navigation

I want the category list to have checkboxes so that the visitor can navigate much more easily, just like the way Amazon does it.

Compare: left is my current layout, right is what I want to achieve
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [the Taxonomy Drill-Down plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/). Depending on your configuration, it might be better to create multiple taxonomies: one for brands, one for features, ...

[Drill-down navigation widgets http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshot-1.png?r=389850](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshot-1.png?r=389850)